# My navigation form in Access screws up my queries and subforms

Tags: ms-access

I have created an inputForm with the ability to call other subforms and everything works great. However, when I put the inputForm within a navigation form, Access can't find the proper objects and subforms. For example, I reference my subforms using:

```
Forms("inputProtocolform")!newProtocol.Value = Null
```

But within the navigation form, this line of code throws an error. I assume it's because of the tab? Still, is there a simple fix? I have lots of code lines similar to the above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the "full path" to the subform.

```
Forms!NavigationForm!inputProtocolform.Form!newProtocol.Value = Null
```

This assumes that the **subform control** on `NavigationForm` has the same name as the subform itself (`inputProtocolform`)

See [Forms: Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)